# Two transactions at the same time and duplicated data

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, transactions

I have an API which is receiving two requests at exactly the same time. It results in two transactions being run at the same time as well, and so in duplicating the data. The pseudo code of my endpoint is:

```
public function myEndpoint(Request $request)
{
  $newOrderID = $request->get('order_id');

  DB::beginTransaction();

  try {
    $ordersCount = Order::where(['id' => $newOrderID])->count();
    if ($ordersCount === 0) {
      Order::create(['id' => $newOrderID]);
      
      $stat = Stat::where(['date' => Carbon::now()])->first();
      $stat->orders_count = $stat->orders_count + 1;
      $stat->save();
    }

    DB::commit();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
  }
}
```

So the endpoint is a transaction that:

- saves new order ID to the table
- increments statistics

The orders table does not have the unique key. It checks for the duplicates, and if there is an order ID already, it should not do anything.

The problem is - two transactions running at the same time, there is no duplicate yet, and the data gets duplicated, so I end up having two rows with the same order ID.

Setting the unique key will not work, because the statistics table will always get incorrectly incremented anyway.

Is there a nice solution to this problem?

Comment: Assuming your order ID is just some arbitrary (unique) auto increment value, it cannot be used for detecting duplicates anyway.  What other information exists between the two incoming inserts which might tip us off that one/both are duplicates?  We need to know this in order to answer here.

Comment: Order ID is a generated ID that is passed to the endpoint as a query parameter, like `https://example.com/api/my-endpoint?order_id=n1992bb3j1bbb3`. Sending this request in parallel multiple times with the same order ID will sometimes result in condition I explained.

Comment: Can you tell us about this "statistics" table?  What is happening there such that a unique index would not be suitable here?

Comment: "statistics" table holds the number of inserts into "orders" table. Unique index would be perfect, if - the query would not update the "statistics" table on duplicate key in "orders" table. But it's not really possible, is it? For example, on duplicate key insert to "orders", the query will not insert redundant data there, but it will still update the counter in the "statistics" table.

Comment: How about using `lockForUpdate` on checking for duplicate order ID, so that the other transactions will need to wait?

Comment: Maybe look into using an `INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` type of query.

Comment: Yes but then statistics table will still always get updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a hash and lock incoming requests if same order_id is already processing

1. Make a Hash
2. When request comes in check if order id in Hash

   1. If already in hash return duplicate request
3. Check if order_id in DB
4. Insert In DB if not exists
5. Clear order_id from hash

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql trigger to resolve the duplicate entry. Here is the sample trigger. You don't have to check `if exist` in php code.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS order_transaction_before_insert;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  TRIGGER order_transaction_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON order FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE msg varchar(128);
    DECLARE foundCount INT;


    SET foundCount = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM order
        WHERE
              order_id = NEW.order_id
    );

    IF( foundCount > 0) THEN
        SET msg = CONCAT('DuplicateEntryError: Trying to insert a duplicate value in order table for driver: ', NEW.order_id);
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT =  msg;
    END IF;

END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```